# Error: You must specify exactly one target process

Tags: cpu-load, top, syntax, resource-limiting, cpulimit

what is the syntax to use `cpulimit` to throttle `Web Content`?  Note the space between `Web` and `Content`.

```
top - 09:16:00 up  1:09,  2 users,  load average: 1.80, 1.70, 1.77
Tasks: 215 total,   2 running, 213 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 50.9 us,  3.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 45.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  2038672 total,   555984 free,   890712 used,   591976 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  2084860 total,  1660224 free,   424636 used.   874444 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                   
 4990 thufir    20   0 1448076 515220  78576 R  92.7 25.3  14:42.98 Web Content                               
 3797 thufir    20   0 1280048 272272  65268 S  11.6 13.4   5:23.12 firefox
```

error:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cpulimit -z -b -l 22 -e web content
Error: You must specify exactly one target process
thufir@doge:~$ CPUlimit version 2.1
Usage: cpulimit TARGET [OPTIONS...] [-- PROGRAM]
   TARGET must be exactly one of these:
      -p, --pid=N        pid of the process
      -e, --exe=FILE     name of the executable program file
                         The -e option only works when
                         cpulimit is run with admin rights.
      -P, --path=PATH    absolute path name of the
                         executable program file
   OPTIONS
      -b  --background   run in background
      -c  --cpu=N        override the detection of CPUs on the machine.
      -l, --limit=N      percentage of cpu allowed from 1 up.
                         Usually 1 - 200, but can be higher
                         on multi-core CPUs (mandatory)
      -q, --quiet        run in quiet mode (only print errors).
      -k, --kill         kill processes going over their limit
                         instead of just throttling them.
      -r, --restore      Restore processes after they have
                         been killed. Works with the -k flag.
      -s, --signal=SIG   Send this signal to the watched process when cpulimit exits.
                         Signal should be specificed as a number or 
                         SIGTERM, SIGCONT, SIGSTOP, etc. SIGCONT is the default.
      -v, --verbose      show control statistics
      -z, --lazy         exit if there is no suitable target process,
                         or if it dies
          --             This is the final CPUlimit option. All following
                         options are for another program we will launch.
      -h, --help         display this help and exit
q
The program 'q' can be found in the following packages:
 * python-q-text-as-data
 * python3-q-text-as-data
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
thufir@doge:~$
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? And what is "Web Content"? Can you show the output of `ps 4446` (where 4446 is the PID if the "Web Content" process as shown in `top`)? Note that you can also tell `cpulimit` the PID of a process, using the `-p` instead of `-e` option. Otherwise you could try quoting the "Web Content" process name.

Comment: seems to be firefox / javascript/ flash /something related.  killing it never causes system prob.  stuck script?  no due diligence on what it is.

Comment: `The -e option only works when
                         cpulimit is run with admin rights.`